# Сборщик Vite. Не могу передать свой localhost на другое устройство по ip, но на CRA это работает

Tags: reactjs, ip, localhost, vite

Я читал документацию vite и другие статьи на счет этого, но не смог реализовать - новичок в этом деле. Помогите)
На CRA http://{ip}:{port} работает, на vite нет.

Comment: Vite же не сервер

Answer (score 0):

Я смог реализовать это). Во время запуска проекта вписал npm run dev -- --host {ip}. А потом на другом устройстве открыл это.